# Compile|Build Error Maven [ERROR] : xsbti.CompileFaile

Tags: scala, maven, build, compilation, dependencies

1.Continuously facing this weird error, have deleted complete m2 folder, still no luck.

````
    ```[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  1.823 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-27T18:04:23+05:30
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (main-scalac) on project athena-core: Execution main-scalac of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile: xsbti/CompileFailed
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/net/alchim31/maven/scala-maven-plugin/3.2.0/scala-maven-plugin-3.2.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
    [ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
    [ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
    [ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
    [ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.2/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.2/plexus-io-2.0.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
    [ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1.2/doxia-sink-api-1.1.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1.2/doxia-logging-api-1.1.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.0.11/maven-invoker-2.0.11.jar
    [ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/ankit.maloo/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/zinc/zinc/0.3.5/zinc-0.3.5.jar
    [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
    [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] : xsbti.CompileFailed
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException```
````

When ran in debug mode, got gthe cause of the error, can't understand what does it mean.
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbti.CompileFailed`

Comment: can you share you pom.xml

Comment: I am facing the same error, no solution found?